# Having per group one value from column based on the comparision on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on the filtering the dataframe based on the value of one column and then using the same column as output of another column

suppose I have following dataframe

```
   group  AAA  BBB  TGT
0     A   1.0  NaN  1.0
1     A   1.0  NaN  NaN
2     B   NaN  1.0  NaN
3     B   1.0  NaN  NaN
4     B   1.0  NaN  NaN
5     C   NaN  NaN  NaN
6     C   1.0  NaN  1.0
7     C   1.0  NaN  NaN
```

I would like to have the value of the TGT column based on

1. If AAA value per group has value 1.0 before BBB then use that in TGT Column once per group. Example (row0, row1, row6, row7)
2. If AAA value per group comes after the BBB then do not count that in TGT Column example (row 2, row 3, row 4).

I tried in following way but unable to get the correct value

```
# Fill NaN values with a large negative value for comparison purposes
df.fillna(-9999, inplace=True)

# Filter rows where 'AAA' > 'BBB'
filtered_df = df.query('AAA > BBB')

# Group by 'group' column and get the first row of each group

filtered_df_group = filtered_df.groupby(df['group']).nth(0)
filtered_df_group ['TGT'] = 1

# set in the original df

df.loc[filtered_df_group.index, "TGT"] = filtered_df_group["TGT"]
```

Would you please help me to get the desired output ?

I tried to use group by and filter via appearance before another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
df2 = df.dropna(subset=['AAA','BBB'],how = 'all')

df.assign(TGT = df2['AAA'].gt(df2['BBB'],fill_value=0).groupby(df['group']).head(1).loc[lambda x: x].astype(int))
```

or

```
m = df.groupby('group').idxmax()

df.loc[m.where(m.eq(m.min(axis=1),axis=0))['AAA'].dropna(),'TGT'] = 1
```

or:

```
df.loc[df[['AAA','BBB']].mul(df.index,axis=0).groupby(df['group']).first().mask(lambda x: x['BBB'].le(x['AAA']))['AAA'].dropna(how = 'all'),'TGT'] = 1
```

Output:

```
  group  AAA  BBB  TGT
0     A  1.0  NaN  1.0
1     A  1.0  NaN  NaN
2     B  NaN  1.0  NaN
3     B  1.0  NaN  NaN
4     B  1.0  NaN  NaN
5     C  NaN  NaN  NaN
6     C  1.0  NaN  1.0
7     C  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom function:

- fill valid values from top to bottom `ffill()`
- fill remain null values by 0 `fillna(0)`
- compute the difference between BBB and AAA `diff(axis=1)`

Finally, get the first row where the difference is strictly positive.

```
def first_valid_aaa(x):
    diff = x[['BBB', 'AAA']].ffill().fillna(0).diff(axis=1)['AAA']
    return x.loc[diff > 0, 'AAA'].head(1)

df['TGT'] = df.groupby('group').apply(first_valid_aaa).droplevel('group')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  group  AAA  BBB  TGT
0     A  1.0  NaN  1.0
1     A  1.0  NaN  NaN
2     B  NaN  1.0  NaN
3     B  1.0  NaN  NaN
4     B  1.0  NaN  NaN
5     C  NaN  NaN  NaN
6     C  1.0  NaN  1.0
7     C  1.0  NaN  NaN
```